# kubernetes convert single master to multi master

Tags: kubernetes

I have created the single master kubernetes `v1.9.0` cluster using kubeadm command in bare metal  server.  Now I want to add two more master and make it multi master.

Is it possible to convert to multi master configuration? Is there a document available for this type of conversation?

I have found this link for `Kops` not sure same steps will work for other environment also.

https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/single-to-multi-master.md

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible, but you may need to break your master setup temporarily.
You'll need to follow the instructions [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/)

In a nutshell:

Create a kubeadm config file. In that kubeadm config file you'll need to include the SAN for the loadbalancer you'll use. Example:

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha2
kind: MasterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: v1.11.0
apiServerCertSANs:
- "LOAD_BALANCER_DNS"
api:
    controlPlaneEndpoint: "LOAD_BALANCER_DNS:LOAD_BALANCER_PORT"
etcd:
  local:
    extraArgs:
      listen-client-urls: "https://127.0.0.1:2379,https://CP0_IP:2379"
      advertise-client-urls: "https://CP0_IP:2379"
      listen-peer-urls: "https://CP0_IP:2380"
      initial-advertise-peer-urls: "https://CP0_IP:2380"
      initial-cluster: "CP0_HOSTNAME=https://CP0_IP:2380"
    serverCertSANs:
      - CP0_HOSTNAME
      - CP0_IP
    peerCertSANs:
      - CP0_HOSTNAME
      - CP0_IP
networking:
    # This CIDR is a Calico default. Substitute or remove for your CNI provider.
    podSubnet: "192.168.0.0/16"
```

Copy the certificates created to your new nodes. All the certs under `/etc/kubernetes/pki/` should be copied

Copy the `admin.conf` from `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` to the new nodes

Example:

```
USER=ubuntu # customizable
CONTROL_PLANE_IPS="10.0.0.7 10.0.0.8"
for host in ${CONTROL_PLANE_IPS}; do
    scp /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt "${USER}"@$host:
    scp /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.key "${USER}"@$host:
    scp /etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.key "${USER}"@$host:
    scp /etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.pub "${USER}"@$host:
    scp /etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt "${USER}"@$host:
    scp /etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.key "${USER}"@$host:
    scp /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt "${USER}"@$host:etcd-ca.crt
    scp /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.key "${USER}"@$host:etcd-ca.key
    scp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf "${USER}"@$host:
done
```

Create your second kubeadm config file for the second node:

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha2
kind: MasterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: v1.11.0
apiServerCertSANs:
- "LOAD_BALANCER_DNS"
api:
    controlPlaneEndpoint: "LOAD_BALANCER_DNS:LOAD_BALANCER_PORT"
etcd:
  local:
    extraArgs:
      listen-client-urls: "https://127.0.0.1:2379,https://CP1_IP:2379"
      advertise-client-urls: "https://CP1_IP:2379"
      listen-peer-urls: "https://CP1_IP:2380"
      initial-advertise-peer-urls: "https://CP1_IP:2380"
      initial-cluster: "CP0_HOSTNAME=https://CP0_IP:2380,CP1_HOSTNAME=https://CP1_IP:2380"
      initial-cluster-state: existing
    serverCertSANs:
      - CP1_HOSTNAME
      - CP1_IP
    peerCertSANs:
      - CP1_HOSTNAME
      - CP1_IP
networking:
    # This CIDR is a calico default. Substitute or remove for your CNI provider.
    podSubnet: "192.168.0.0/16"
```

Replace the following variables with the correct addresses for this node:

LOAD_BALANCER_DNS

LOAD_BALANCER_PORT

CP0_HOSTNAME

CP0_IP

CP1_HOSTNAME

CP1_IP

Move the copied certs to the correct location

```
USER=ubuntu # customizable
  mkdir -p /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd
  mv /home/${USER}/ca.crt /etc/kubernetes/pki/
  mv /home/${USER}/ca.key /etc/kubernetes/pki/
  mv /home/${USER}/sa.pub /etc/kubernetes/pki/
  mv /home/${USER}/sa.key /etc/kubernetes/pki/
  mv /home/${USER}/front-proxy-ca.crt /etc/kubernetes/pki/
  mv /home/${USER}/front-proxy-ca.key /etc/kubernetes/pki/
  mv /home/${USER}/etcd-ca.crt /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
  mv /home/${USER}/etcd-ca.key /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.key
  mv /home/${USER}/admin.conf /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
```

Now, you can start adding the master using `kubeadm`

```
  kubeadm alpha phase certs all --config kubeadm-config.yaml
  kubeadm alpha phase kubelet config write-to-disk --config kubeadm-config.yaml
  kubeadm alpha phase kubelet write-env-file --config kubeadm-config.yaml
  kubeadm alpha phase kubeconfig kubelet --config kubeadm-config.yaml
  systemctl start kubelet
```

Join the node to the etcd cluster:

```
  CP0_IP=10.0.0.7
  CP0_HOSTNAME=cp0
  CP1_IP=10.0.0.8
  CP1_HOSTNAME=cp1

  KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf kubectl exec -n kube-system etcd-${CP0_HOSTNAME} -- etcdctl --ca-file /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --cert-file /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.crt --key-file /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.key --endpoints=https://${CP0_IP}:2379 member add ${CP1_HOSTNAME} https://${CP1_IP}:2380
  kubeadm alpha phase etcd local --config kubeadm-config.yaml
```

and then finally, add the controlplane:

```
  kubeadm alpha phase kubeconfig all --config kubeadm-config.yaml
  kubeadm alpha phase controlplane all --config kubeadm-config.yaml
  kubeadm alpha phase mark-master --config kubeadm-config.yaml
```

Repeat these steps for the third master, and you should be good.

Comment: I know its a pretty old question needed a suggestion around upgrading kubernetes.
Upgrading a multi master cluster with `kubeadm upgrade apply` Do we need to run this command on only one master and then update `kubectl` binary and then restarting every thing or we need to run this `kubeadm upgrade apply` on every master then cordon rest of the nodes and then restart

Comment: In your scp script, you make it sound like the two NEW master nodes are 10.0.0.7 and 10.0.0.8 (because of CONTROL_PLANE_IPS="10.0.0.7 10.0.0.8"). Then later, in the "Join the node to the etcd cluster" part, it looks like CP0 is the original master node, but the IP it's set to is 10.0.0.7. I'd assume the original node is 10.0.0.6. Or is it actually just that in the scp script it should be "CONTROL_PLANE_IPS="10.0.0.8 10.0.0.9", and everything else is correct?